# Changing data and value from an object in an href

Tags: javascript, html, twitch

Hello I am trying to change the data of a object and the value of a parameter inside the embedding code from twitch.
I am not that good on javascript and could use some help.
Actually my script works with and input button, but i wanted to refresh the twitch video with a link

My Html code :

```
<div id="streamHolder">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" bgcolor="#000000">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
        <param id="param" name="flashvars" />
    </object>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="text" id="streamName" placeholder="Enter Streamer Name Here" style="width:12em;">
    <input type="button" id="button1" onclick="changestream1();" value="Change Stream">
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="changestream1(riotgames);" id="streamName" value="Change Stream">riotgames</a>
```

My Javascript code :

```
function changestream1() {
    var streamInput = document.getElementById('streamName').value;
    var streamIn = ''; //This variable is not defined yet used on the last line of this block;
    var object = document.getElementById('live_embed_player_flash');
    var param = document.getElementById('param');
    object.setAttribute("data", "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + streamInput);
    param.setAttribute("value", "hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=" + streamInput + "&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" + streamIn);
}
```

if you need a visual of how i am thinking this out press Link :D 
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F65Dw/15/)

Regards, Rac3Mul.

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs a parameter:

```
function changestream1(parameter) {
        var streamInput;
        if(parameter == riotgames)
        {
              streamInput = riotgames;
        }
        else
        {
              streamInput = whatever;
         }
        //do something
}
```

Hope this helps.